# FPS in World of Warcraft with Wine

Tags: 11.10, wine, opengl

I'm  using Bumblebee 3.0 (also tried Ironhide) (I have a Dell XPS 15) however my FPS is 8 when flying above Stormwind looking down at the AH. On Windows this was 18 FPS while having the graphics even higher **and** in D3D.

Is there anything what I could try to improve performance? Due to the fact I'm using OpenGL many graphics features are not available which means basically that my FPS should be a lot higher.

I'm using Wine 1.4 RC1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not expect the same performance using Wine compared with Windows. Wine as you probably know is used to emulate all layers necessary to run Windows applications, it will never be the same as you have in a Windows system.

For increasing the FPS I would suggest running all your gaming sessions under Unity2D, that is important because you do not have the composite desktop taking part of your graphics card performance.

For World of Warcraft as you said changing from D3D to OpenGL helps in most cases bit in the end you will have to eventually lower the graphic details options to run the game.

Try a lower resolution, decrease the graphic details a bit and them some more until you are happy with the performance.

When I played World of Warcraft on my Ubuntu system I noticed 2 things always: lag and ping to server was much better and graphics quality always had to be much lower than the one I used in Windows.

Comment: Fair enough and currently I am already running Unity2D. If I can't get it better, I'll just reinstall Win7 back. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: I have added a bit more commenting on this, I am not sure but I would not expect a "do this" and things start miraculously improving answer. Its a shame I know, blame Blizzard for being lame to never provide a Linux client!

Comment: Well thanks, I've disabled compiz using `metacity --replace` but still no improvement in FPS. I guess I'll switch over to Windows.. and only for the games it is.